# Is it possible to use a subset of larger struct's items as a function's parameter (mapping to a smaller struct)?

Tags: go

Say I have the following structs

```
package foobar

type Foo struct{}

type Bar struct{}

func (*Bar) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) { 
    return 0, nil 
}
```

Somewhere in my application I intend to consume one of these structs like this

```
package consumer

type DoOptions struct {
    bar io.Reader
}

func Do(opts *DoOptions) {
    fmt.Println(opts)
}
```

My objective is to have a general dependency container and have the clients stipulate which dependencies they wish to take from it.

```
package main

type dependencyContainer struct {
    foo *Foo
    bar *Bar
}

func main() {
    s := &dependencyContainer{
        foo: &foobar.Foo{},
        bar: &foobar.Bar{},
    }
    consumer.Do(s)
}
```

But of course this doesn't work as:

```
cannot use s (variable of type *dependencyContainer) as *DoOptions value in argument to consumer
```

Is there some way for me to achieve this?

Looking at alternatives and they are all quite janky.

- Interfaces can only have methods in them
- `context.Context` means a lot of unnecessary casting and the function's API gets messy
- Having multiple function arguments can be high upkeep with import order mattering and repetition as you drill properties down your dependency graph

Comment: Have you considered passing the dependency container to the `Do` method, and have each consumer explicitly *select* their dependencies from the container?

Comment: @mkopriva the thing is I want the consumer to have no knowledge of it's ambient context (like a library). While using a struct as an argument is less standard than parameters, it's still more abstract than hard coding the orchestrator's dependency context.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, if you need to hide irrelevant dependencies from a consumer, and one that is fairly close to your initial design of the orchestrator, is to use interfaces. The limitation of interfaces being only behaviour and no data (i.e. no fields) can be overcome with getters. For example: https://play.golang.com/p/V3lPvdMo5yI

Answer (score 0):

What you want looks very similar to the [Functional Options](https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/options-pattern/) pattern. Remember that functions are first-class citizens in Go, so you can pass data around via functions (or functors - `struct`s with an "`apply`" method).

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type do struct{}

type DoOption func(*do)

func Do(opts ...DoOption) {
    do := do{}
    for _, opt := range opts {
        opt(&do)
    } // "apply" the options
    // use the values...
}

type Foo struct{ value string }

type Bar struct{ value string }

func WithFoo(x Foo) func(*do) {
    return func(*do) { fmt.Println(x.value) }
}

func WithBar(x Bar) func(*do) {
    return func(*do) { fmt.Println(x.value) }
}

type dependencyContainer struct {
    foo Foo
    bar Bar
}

func main() {
    s := dependencyContainer{Foo{"foo"}, Bar{"bar"}}
    Do(WithFoo(s.foo), WithBar(s.bar))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/48rCTwn1f9C

Also, many argue that explicit dependency injection (i.e. exposing all dependencies via the constructor instead of hiding them in the consumer's code) leads to a better maintainable code.

Comment: While I agree with you, the objective is to have all the dependencies injected via the constructer explicitly.

Using an object as a parameter retains the benefit and ensures dependency order doesn't matter.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEITgbwF8AoY0SWRVDOAIRSgOLkQgDs0YoBXBGaOAApmLOGCgBLAG4oYwOADNcALmy4RASgIkSZcNHjJ0mACLAwwNgBNLCCcEz4RYbgCMkEhItxwAvHDZgAHc1CEENZzcPL1cGPwDgugZBGAALCTQAOiUICN0YAE8LOABhdjRuAFtgKAB5MBgJcvinFlioVXooYl0FbjY+JrZWDiqawQgGobRVMtHquqnyrVaRtAgkYEykCABzCaWOTPa80ikICStFfsH2OEqUCTZwphYEcvgbC2tbe0x-QIhMzfGwDP7hETvebjL6WUF2Bx5IA

Answer (score -4):

> Is there some way for me to achieve this?

No. Redesign.